# SELECT between two DateTimePicker values

Tags: sql, vb.net

I'm a little stumped with this and hope someone can help!

I am trying to do an SQL SELECT command to display a set of values with the dates set between DateTimePicker1 and DateTimePicker2, This is the code I have:

```
        If ComboBox1.Text = "All" Then
        da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Times WHERE ([Date] BETWEEN '" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "' AND '" & DateTimePicker2.Value & "')", MyConn)
        da.Fill(ds, "Times")
        Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
        source1.DataSource = view1
        DataGridView1.DataSource = view1
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

This code is kind of working.... It's pulling the information out of the Access database (I'm restricted to using Access...) and displpaying it within the DataGrid.

The trouble I'm having is that it's selecting everything from the dd between the range, ie:

DateTimePicker1 is equal to 03/08/2015
DateTimePicker2 is equal to 05/08/2015

The data being pulled back is:

```
03/06/2015
04/06/2015
05/06/2015
03/07/2015
04/07/2015
05/07/2015
03/08/2015
04/08/2015
05/08/2015
```

Seems to only be using the dd value rather than the whole date value..

I'm thinking it's just a syntax error but I'm really struggling to figure out where!

Thanks!

I've now changed the code to:

```
    If ComboBox1.Text = "All" Then
        Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Times WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate"
        Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, MyConn)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", DateTimePicker1.Value)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndpDate", DateTimePicker2.Value)
        Dim da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(ds, "Times")
        Dim view1 As New DataView(tables(0))
        source1.DataSource = view1
        DataGridView1.DataSource = view1
        Exit Sub
    End If
```

This isn't displaying any data at all... it's not throwing any errors and it is pulling the headers through but just displaying no data.. Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: If you pass the DTP values as SQL parameters then the problem is very likely to go away.

Comment: @AndrewMorton also it's great practice from a security perspective as it will avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always use sql parameters(f.e. to prevent sql-injection), that'll probably also fix this issue:

```
Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Times WHERE [Date] BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate"
Dim cmd = New OleDbCommand(sql, MyConn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", DateTimePicker1.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndpDate", DateTimePicker2.Value);
Dim da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
```

Maybe you also want to truncate the time portion of the `DateTime`:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndpDate", DateTimePicker2.Value.Date);
```

Bu since `DateTimePicker2.Value.Date` truncates the time it means that you select from midnight and not later at that day. Then you need to include the end-date by adding one day, so `DateTimePicker2.Value.Date.AddDays(1)`. But that will also include data of the next day if that is midnight. So instead of using `Between` its always better to use `>=` and `<`.

So this is a better approach:

```
Dim sql = "SELECT * FROM Times WHERE [Date] >= @StartDate AND [Date] < @EndDate"

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StartDate", DateTimePicker1.Value.Date);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EndpDate", DateTimePicker2.Value.Date.AddDays(1));
```

Comment: Seems to be getting an issue on the `da.SelectCommand = cmd` line, it's telling me that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." My da is defined as `Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter` -  Apologies, I'm really new to VB!

Comment: @WillRyan: fixed, mistakenly used `SqlCommand` instead of `OleDbCommand`. I've also used the constructor of `OleDbDataAdapter` to initialize the dataadapter.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've just updated the question as it's not displaying any data now...

Comment: @WillRyan: just out of curioisity, this code is in an  `If ComboBox1.Text = "All"` which means you want to show all data. Why do you apply a `Where` filter at all here? Acc. to the issue that you dont get the expected result, it's difficult to help without sample data. I don't even know what `03/08/2015` is, third of august or 8th of march?

Comment: It's details based on users, I want to show all logs for all users between a certain date range. I noticed that the DTP was outputting MM/dd/yy so I've changed the format to dd/MM/yyyy and I'm still getting the same issue of it only displaying data based on the dd section

Comment: @WillRyan: maybe you have used `DateTimePicker1.Value.Date` and `DateTimePicker2.Value.Date` which truncates the time which means you select from midnight. Then you need to include the end-date by adding one day, so `DateTimePicker2.Value.Date.AddDays(1)`. But that will also include data of the next day if that is midnight. So instead of using `Between` its always better to use `>=` and `<`.

Comment: Turns out it was something simple... the Access database that the information is contained on was set to hold the data as a string rather than a date... Changed that setting and it started working perfectly! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

if you sill struggling try using < & > operators :

```
da = New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Times WHERE ([Date] >= 'DateTimePicker1.Value' &&  [Date] <= 'DateTimePicker2.Value')", MyConn)
```